# PHP: Output seconds in H:M value

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
echo $diff . ' / ';
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $diff);
```

This produces

```
129600 / 12:00:00
```

However 129600 is 36 hours and not 12, so how could I amend the code to be total hours (36) rather than being 1 day and 12 hours as I don't need to show the day

So if it was 36 hours and 1 minute, I'd want to show: `36:01`  or `36:1`

Thanks

Comment: 36 hours is 24+12 hours. So 12 hours is correct, there's just a day in addition. If you format by `d H:i:s` you'll see it.

Comment: I want to show 36 hours as per my question however

Comment: I also want to show any minutes so if it was 12:01PM I'd want 36:01

Comment: _“I want to show 36 hours”_ - then stop using date formatting functions to begin with, these are not suitable for what you want in the first place. Do the math yourself, it’s not really that hard …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hours = floor($diff/ 3600);
$minutes = floor(($diff/ 60) % 60);
$seconds = $diff% 60;

$diff= $hours . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $seconds ;

echo $diff ;
```

Try this. This may give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the days, multiply it by 24 - then add the hours to that, and append the minutes and seconds.

Note that if you have more than 30/31 days, this will stop working again and you will need to account for *months* or possibly *years* as well.

```php
$days = gmdate("d", $diff);
$hours = gmdate("H", $diff);
echo ($days*24 + $hours).gmdate(":i:s", $diff);
```

You can instead go the other way around - extract the seconds and minutes!

```php
$seconds = str_pad($diff % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$minutes = str_pad($diff/60 % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$hours = str_pad($diff/3600, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/Aa8E6

Comment: This doesn't work if it's 08-05-2019 12:00 AM and 09-05-2019 12:00 PM - it brings back 60

Comment: It's probably better to go the other way around then - extract the hours and minutes from seconds. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of your comment : This doesn't work if it's 08-05-2019 12:00 AM and 09-05-2019 12:00 PM - it brings back 60. 
Try following code

```
$sstartdate = new DateTime('08-05-2019 12:00:00 AM');
$edatetime = new DateTime('09-05-2019 12:00:00 PM');
$since_start = $sstartdate->diff($edatetime);

$hours = ($since_start->days * 24)+($since_start->h);
$min = $since_start->i;
$sec = $since_start->s;

echo $hours.':'.$min;
```

`Output: 36:00`  
36 hours and 00 minute